# How to add buy button to individual products in a product grid in Shopify

Tags: shopify, checkout

In my shopify site. The page which shows all products have an add to cart button. But I also need a buy button for each of the products as well in that page.You can see the buy buttons there they are not working properly, it is only doing the action of chekout button from the cart page. It would simply go the checkout page of the Cart.

[image]

I need to add a buy button which can go the checkout page of that individual product.
This is the code I have used to make the current buy button which needs fixing

```
<form class="spf-product__form buy_now_button" action="/checkout" method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="spf-product__form-btn-addtocart">
        Buy Now
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't deploy the default buy now button, because they are exclusive for cart and checkout page from Shopify

Comment: You need to use AJAX to add to the cart and on success simply direct the customer to the checkout page. but it still shows handling the product using the cart system.